# Yii2: model with self join relation search issue

Tags: model, yii2, self-join

I have a table that contains url's and info about those sites. Each url can appear once or twice. First and last scan of that site. I want to show data in gridview with enabled search by url and grade of first scan and if exists grade of second scan. When I load all I get correct data. Url, grade, grade2. But when i try to search by grade I get only sites that has been scanned twice so they are twice in the database and sites that are in database only once are ignored.

```
table:

id  url        initial  points  grade
1   blue.com    1         10      F
2   red.com     1         20      F
3   blue.com    0         50      C
etc...
display in gridview works fine

no  url       points grade  points2   grade2
1   blue.com    10     F       50        C
2   red.com     20     F    not set   not set
etc...
```

but when I search by url or grade it only displays results that have second scan in table

¸In model:

```
        public function getParent() {
        return $this->hasOne(self::classname(), ['url' => 'url'])->
                from(self::tableName() . ' AS parent')-
         >onCondition(['parent.initial'=>0]);
            }
          public function getParentid(){
        return $this->parent->id;
           } 
      public function getParentgrade(){
        return $this->parent->grade;
      }
      public function getParentpoints(){
        return $this->parent->points;
      }
```

In search model:

```
    public $parentid;
    public $parentpoints;
    public $parentgrade;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[........'parentpoints'.........], 'integer'],
            [['url', 'parentgrade', .........], 'safe'],
        ];
    }





    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = SitesTemp::find();
        $query->where(['sites_temp.for_scan'=>0, 'sites_temp.initial'=>1]);

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([

            'query' => $query,
        ]);

         $dataProvider->setSort([
            'attributes'=>[
                'url',
                'points',
               'grade',
            'parentgrade'=>[
                'asc'=>['parent.grade'=> SORT_ASC],
                'desc'=>['parent.grade'=> SORT_DESC],
                'label'=>'Last Grade'
            ],
                'parentpoints'=>[
                'asc'=>['parent.points'=> SORT_ASC],
                'desc'=>['parent.points'=> SORT_DESC],
                'label'=>'Last Points'
            ],
                ]
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

         if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {


             $query->joinWith(['parent']);
            return $dataProvider;
        }


        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'sites_temp.id' => $this->id,
            'sites_temp.initial' => $this->initial,
            'sites_temp.points' => $this->points,

        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sites_temp.url', $this->url])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sites_temp.grade', $this->grade])
                     ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'sites_temp.points', $this-
         >points]);

         $query->joinWith(['parent'=>function($q){
            $q->where('parent.grade like "%'.$this->parentgrade.'%"');
        }]);  

        return $dataProvider;
       }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

I need to put joinWith only if search parameter exists. So

```
if(!empty($this->parentgrade)){
         $query->joinWith([parent=>function($q){
            $q->where('parent.grade like "%'.$this->parentgrade.'%"');
        }]); }
```

solved my issue